# Exception while using Sphinx to document script with command line arguments

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Is there any way I can use Sphinx to document the command line inputs of a python script? I am able to document inputs of functions or methods but I don't know how to document inputs of scripts. I have been trying to follow the same syntax I use for functions by adding in the source file the line `.. automodule:: scriptLDOnServer` where scriptLDOnServer is my python script (which corresponds to my main).

The problem is that I get an error like this:

```
__import__(self.modname)
File "/home/ubuntu/SVNBioinfo/trunk/Code/LD/scriptLDOnServer.py", line 10, in <module>
    genotype_filename=sys.argv[7];
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It seems that Sphinx is trying to get the command line inputs but in my source file there are no inputs so the import fails. Is there a way to solve this? Should I use another command in the source for a script instead of a module?

Sorry for not being very clear but it is difficult to explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing while you are importing the file because you are trying to access `sys.argv[7]` *at import time*. This is not something you should be doing. Such code which can possibly fail should be either in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block or in a function, so that it won't be executed when the code is imported.

This holds generally. You should never* write code which will fail to import or which has *any* side-effects of being imported.

*<sub>* Conditions apply. But you'd better have pretty good justification before breaking this rule.</sub>*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was not aware that the main function had to be enclosed in those tags

Comment: Another situation demonstrating why importing should be safe is `help('modules')`; it goes and finds everything that can be imported and imports it. If you've got something that causes a crash or exit (a few do - it's universally a bug) it breaks it.

Comment: How can i comment input parameters for a module, I tried using the same syntax used for functions (:param name_parameter:) but it does not seem to recognize it for module input parameters(argv). What is the best way of documenting these parameters?

Comment: @Rossella: your module should not be depending on sys.argv unless it is an entry-point. If it is, use [command-line program markup](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/desc.html#command-line-program-markup).

Comment: it is an entry point, that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot